# Grant User Permission To Restore Database And Access that database in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to create a user having `db_create`, `db_restore` server roles and will be `db_owner` of that database. But there is only 1 server role available, that is `db_creator`, which can create database  and is also the `db_owner` of that. But when I restore another database backup that gets disconnected, i.e. not accessible.

In sql server is there any way that can create and restore db and will be `dbowner` of that database. I don't want to grant `sysadmin` server roles to that user.

Please help me out.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but GRANTing "ALTER ANY DATABASE" in addition to dbcreator might do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

> But when I restore another database backup that gets disconnected, i.e. not accessible.

You have to [add the user to the db_owner role](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/29348/8783) **after** the restore. You can use

```
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [frank]
```

or `EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'frank';`

Note:

[**ALTER ANY DATABASE**](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1714/server-level-permissions-for-sql-server-2005-and-sql-server-2008/) - You dont want to give the user too much rights since this will allow the user rights for all the databases.

> Grants or denies the ability to drop or modify existing databases as well as create new databases. The dbcreator fixed server role has this permission granted implicitly.